# linux docker mount namespace

Tags: linux, docker

I use docker to create a container. When I enter the container, I can't see the overload related mount. This is normal,

```
root@django-work:~/test# docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@52110483ac09:/# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          49G   17G   30G  36% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda3        49G   17G   30G  36% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/asound
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
root@52110483ac09:/#
```

But why can I see the complete mount information when I create a PID namespace and mount namespace through unshare

```
root@django-work:~# df -h 
tmpfs           793M  2.0M  791M    1% /run
/dev/sda3        49G   17G   30G   36% /
tmpfs           3.9G   32M  3.9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       512M  5.3M  507M    2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           793M  5.8M  787M    1% /run/user/1000
overlay          49G   17G   30G   36% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/dddc4d45086e3b814fe5589af09becc35cfa7cf4cce1a8fc82a930fba94a70ed/merged
root@django-work:~# unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc /bin/bash
root@django-work:~# df -h 
/dev/sda3        49G   17G   30G   36% /
tmpfs           3.9G   32M  3.9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           793M  2.0M  791M    1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           793M  5.8M  787M    1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       512M  5.3M  507M    2% /boot/efi
overlay          49G   17G   30G   36% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/dddc4d45086e3b814fe5589af09becc35cfa7cf4cce1a8fc82a930fba94a70ed/merged
root@django-work:~#
```

Comment: When I use docker to create a container, I can't see the overlay mounting in the container. I think this is correct. When I use unshare to create PID namespace and mount namespace, why can I still see the overlay mounting information on the host

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of [`mount_namespaces`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html):

> If the namespace is created using unshare(2), the mount list of the new namespace is a copy of the mount list in the caller's previous mount namespace.

You see the same output because when you do `unshare` you initially get a copy of the mount list. But if you make any changes in either namespace, those changes won't be visible in the other.